# Resolution of the dependency failed-I/O Exception

Tags: c#, exception, object, io, unity-container

I am calling a method GetData from a class DataProvider, where the method is implemented as a interface. Calling is done as:

```
Response = ObjectRegistry.Instance.Resolve<IDataProvider>().GetData(id).
```

Structure of the interface looks like.

```
namespace A.B.C.D
{
  ///<Summary>
/// Gets the answer
///</Summary>
    public interface IDataProvider
    {

        GetDataInfo GetData(int id);
    }
}
```

and my DataProvider class looks like.

```
namespace A.B.C.D
{
   public class DataProvider : IDataProvider
    {

       public GetDataInfo GetData(int id)
       {
           GetDataInfo DataInfo = new GetDataInfo();
           //return obj;

         return DataInfo;
      }
}
}
```

But when I am trying to execute this I am getting following error:

```
 Message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = ".DataInfo.IDataProvider", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, DataInfo.IDataProvider, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving DataInfo.IDataProvider,(none)
```

Tried searching in almost all the SO posts, but couldn't find any helpful suggestion

Comment: Could You post your type registration? It would help track the problem ;)

Comment: You probably didn't register an implementation for this `IDataProvider`.

Comment: Or you registered it with a name and now you are trying to resolve the unnamed.